# playerID was deprecated in IOS 8: use player

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, game-center

I have this Game Center function used to lookup players. Recently i downloaded Xcode 6.3 - beta 3.

This is the function:

```
    func lookupPlayers() {
    let playerIDs = match.players.map { ($0 as! GKPlayer).playerID }

    GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(playerIDs) { (players, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("Error retrieving player info: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.matchStarted = false
            self.delegate?.matchEnded()
        } else {
            for player in players {
                println("Found player: \(player.alias)")
                self.playersDict[player.playerID] = player //use player
            }

            self.matchStarted = true
            GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().finishMatchmakingForMatch(self.match)
            self.delegate?.matchStarted()
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode now flags a warning saying "playerID was deprecated in IOS 8: use player"

Can someone help me modify the code to remove the warning. I don't understand what needs to be changed.

Comment: Seems to me like even you aren't sure what that piece of code is supposed to do. You should try to figure out what you need the playersDict for, and if you can change it to an array to avoid using the `playerID` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this, it seems that GKPlayer is not being registered correctly

```
for player in players as! [GKPlayer]
{
    println("Found player: \(player.alias)")
    self.playersDict[player.playerID] = player //use player
}
```

Comment: actually, looking at this again, you are doing duplicate work, you do not even need load players for identity, just do this
`func lookupPlayers() {
   
        for player in match.players {
                println("Found player: \(player.alias)")
                self.playersDict[player.playerID] = player //use player
            }

            self.matchStarted = true
            GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().finishMatchmakingForMatch(self.match)
            self.delegate?.matchStarted()
       
}
`

Now you have a lookup table for your players based on ID